# Python Exscript - use 8022 instead of 22 port with ssh

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, exscript

Is there a possibility of connecting with `ssh` to a different port other than the standard `port 22` in Python `Exscript` module?

If so, how can this be achieved?

Couldn't find anything relevant when browsing the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Protocol.connect` (inherited by `SSH2`) takes an optional `port` parameter:

```
conn = SSH2()
conn.connect(hostname, 8022)
```